# New deployment with "ConfigChange" trigger not started in namespace other than default

Tags: openshift-origin

can someone point me to the right direction. Currently I have following issue:

When I am creating new deployment config in the default namespace with "ConfigChange" trigger first deployment started automatically. But when I am creating same deployment config in other namespace then it's not started automatically but when I starting it manually it finished successfully. Have I missed some configuration point?